# No sound output from builtin speakers on a new laptop

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

The laptop computer is:
ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG Strix G814JI_G814JI
The sudo lspci  reported audio is:
Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 22bd (rev a1)

I know the hardware works because Windows 11 sound works.
In Ubuntu 23.04 the Bluetooth sound is good but no sound output from builtin speakers.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you gone into the sound settings to choose a different output? The Nvidia output is probably a HDMI port so if this is the selected output, that would explain why your built in speakers aren't working

Comment: I have 3 option is sound setting. 2 are Bluetooth and the other is builtin speakers. Is that what you are talking about?